# Java groupingBy: sum multiple fields

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

This question is an extension to the post: [Java 8 groupingby with returning multiple field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728341/java-8-groupingby-with-returning-multiple-field).

For the same problem, how do you return a list of `Customer`? For example, it should return:

```
Customer("A",4500,6500)
Customer("B",3000,3500)
Customer("C",4000,4500)
```

Comment: You want to return a `List` of your `Customer` objects?

Comment: Well, if it's the same problem as the linked post but instead of  `Map<String, List<Double>>` it should return `List<Customer>` then the result should be `[Customer{name='A', total=3500.0, balance=5000.0}, Customer{name='B', total=3000.0, balance=3500.0}, Customer{name='C', total=4000.0, balance=4500.0}]`. your calculation for customer "A" doesnt seem right?

Comment: The calculation of A is correct. There are 3 objects for A in the original problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Pankaj Singhal's post is the right idea if you want a `Map<String, Customer>` as the result set +1. However, I would extract the merging logic into its own function e.g. in the `Customer` class you would have a function as such:

```
public static Customer merge(Customer first, Customer second) {
        first.setTotal(first.getTotal() + second.getTotal());
        first.setBalance(first.getBalance() + second.getBalance());
        return first;
}
```

Then the stream query would become:

```
Map<String, Customer> retObj = 
           listCust.stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Customer::getName, Function.identity(), Customer::merge));
```

- `listCust.stream()` creates a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) object i.e. `Stream<Customer>`.
- [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) performs a mutable reduction operation on the elements of
  this stream using the provided [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html).
- The result of [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) is the provided collector, the `toMap` method extracts the keys  `Customer::getName` and values [`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) and if the mapped keys contain duplicates, the merge function `Customer::merge` is used to resolve collisions.

There are three benefits I see with extracting the merging logic into its own function:

- The code is more compact.
- The code is more readable.
- The complexity of the merging is isolated away from the stream.

---

if however, your intention is to retrieve a `Collection<Customer>`:

```
Collection<Customer> result = listCust.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Customer::getName,
                        Function.identity(),
                        Customer::merge))
                .values();
```

or `List<Customer>` as the result set then all you have to do is call `values()` and pass the result of that to the `ArrayList` constructor:

```
List<Customer> result = new ArrayList<>(listCust.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Customer::getName,
                        Function.identity(),
                        Customer::merge))
                .values());
```

**Update:**

if you don't want to mutate the objects in the source then simply modify the `merge` function as follows:

```
public static Customer merge(Customer first, Customer second) {
        Customer customer = new Customer(first.getName(), first.getTotal(), first.getBalance());
        customer.setTotal(customer.getTotal() + second.getTotal());
        customer.setBalance(customer.getBalance() + second.getBalance());
        return customer;
}
```

and everthing else stays as is.

Comment: Same comment as for the other answer, this mutates the objects in the `Stream` - which you may not want.

Comment: Now you create as new `Customer` for each merge operation - rather hacky.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Hmm, I wouldn't say "hacky" but rather "suboptimal". +1 as your answer seems to avoid that even though we don't know whether the OP really cares about mutating the objects in the source or not :( .

Comment: Fair, suboptimal. I think we have all the bases covered - we'll see what the OP is trying to do. I reckon though, this question is just driven by curiosity rather than an actual problem - from the way it's phrased.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code:

```
Map<String, Customer> retObj =
    listCust.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Customer::getName,
                    Collector.of(
                        Customer::new,
                        (c1, c2) -> {
                            c1.setName(c2.getName());
                            c1.setTotal(c1.getTotal() + c2.getTotal());
                            c1.setBalance(c1.getBalance() + c2.getBalance());
                        },
                        (c3, c4) -> {
                            c3.setTotal(c3.getTotal() + c4.getTotal());
                            c3.setBalance(c3.getBalance() + c4.getBalance());
                            return c3;
                        })));

System.out.println(retObj);
System.out.println(retObj.values());       //If you want only the list of all Customers
```

Output:

```
{
 A=Customer [name=A, total=4500.0, balance=6500.0], 
 B=Customer [name=B, total=3000.0, balance=3500.0], 
 C=Customer [name=C, total=4000.0, balance=4500.0]
}
```

Comment: Note this mutates the objects in the `Stream` - which you may not want. You'd be better of with a custom `Collector` that creates a new `Customer`.

Comment: I really don't like the usage of `toMap` here, rather than `groupingBy`.

Answer (score 3):

The [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51453154/2071828) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51454512/2071828) here are great, but they mutate the `Customer` instances in the input, which may be unexpected.

To avoid this, use a custom `Collector`.

First, create a method that returns a `Collector` that takes a `Stream<Customer>` and merges them into a single `Customer`:

```
public static Collector<Customer, Customer, Customer> customerCollector() {
    return Collector.of(Customer::new, TestBench::merge,
            (l, r) -> {
                merge(l, r);
                return l;
            });
}

public static void merge(final Customer first, final Customer second) {
    first.setName(second.getName());
    first.setTotal(first.getTotal() + second.getTotal());
    first.setBalance(first.getBalance() + second.getBalance());
}
```

This assumes that `Customer` has a noargs constructor.

Then you can do:

```
Collection<Customer> result = listCust.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Customer::getName, customerCollector()))
        .values();
```

Note I use `groupingBy` rather than `toMap` - the `groupingBy` collector is specifially designed to group elements.